# Linking a lib written in C in XCode + Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos

Is it possible to use a library I wrote in C (compiled with GCC on a Mac) on an Objective-C project under XCode?

The project is for a Mac OS X app, not iOS. The library was compiled via GCC on the command line and it is in C (as in C language) and the header for the library (.h file) is a simple C header with function declarations.

If yes, how? Furthermore, do I need to convert the .h files to an objective-c styled header?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at [*Using static libraries with iPhone SDK*](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html).

Comment: Alex thank for the link. The article mentions how to create a lib with an objective-c code and use it, how about a lib (a static lib) written in C and compiled using GCC on the command line?

Comment: This link might help with using a pre-built library: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/

Comment: Thanks again, but again this refer to the creation of an objective-c lib and and .h file with objective-c declarations. How about C, as in the original C? not C++, not objective-c. I have a library compiled with GCC (C language) and a header file (.h) with simple function declarations. Is there a way to use that in XCode for a Mac os X (not iOS) in objective-C?

Comment: Did you read the "Using a static library" section? I think this section refers to using pre-built libraries and headers, not a reference to Objective C or building them in Xcode. The general process should work for iOS apps or OS X applications, I think.

Comment: yes, thank you. but as I mentioned, it's plain C, the same with the header. Would XCode work with this?

Comment: Xcode will work with C, Objective C and C++ files, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Mr Aleph: Objective-C can interface with C code with no problem -- just include the header and link the library.

Comment: @mipadi thanks for the answer. I assume that adding the library to the list of dependencies on the xcode project will make this happen?